# Randomize Audio Played in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

hoping to get a little help here.  I have this HTML code that plays an audio file from a local folder.  I want to add a couple more audio files and have it a play a random file from the array.  I have been searching a lot and trying different things but I haven't found anything that works exactly for my application.

Below is the code I am currently using for one audio file which works just fine.  I really apologize for sloppy script, HTML is not my specialty and I took this from somewhere else:

```
<div>

   <audio id='music' volume='0.1' autoplay controls>

       <source src="myfile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
       Your browser does not support the audio element.    

   </audio>

           <script>
               var audio = document.getElementById("music");
               audio.volume = 0.4;
           </script>        

</div>
```

I have an idea of what I am trying to do based on what I have found for loading random images, I just cannot figure out how to incorporate the same method into my audio file.  I know I am asking for someone to basically write this for me but is there a way to use the method below but for audio in my HTML file?

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    ImageArray = new Array();
    ImageArray[0] = 'image1.jpg';
    ImageArray[1] = 'iamge2.jpg';
    ImageArray[2] = 'iamge3.jpg';
    ImageArray[3] = 'iamge4.jpg';



function getRandomImage() {
    var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * 11);
    var img = ImageArray[num];
    document.getElementById("randImage").innerHTML = ('<img src="' + 'images/random/' + img + '" 
width="250px">')

}
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I've been helpful

```
<audio id="music" volume="0.1" autoplay controls>
</audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addAudio() {
        fileArray = ["file1.mp3", "file2.mp3", "file3.mp3"]
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * fileArray.length);
        var x = document.getElementById("music");
        x.innerHTML = "";
        x.innerHTML += '<source src="audio/' + fileArray[num] + '" type="audio/mpeg">';

        x.play(); 
    }
    addAudio();
</script>
```

EDIT:
Before the browser does something automatically, it requires the user to take some action! My advice is to make the first screen which after interaction calls the next one to start the music. Here I gave you an example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="screen" onclick="addAudio();secondScreen();" style="position: absolute; top:0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;">
        Some Firts Screen (click)
    </div>

    <audio id="music" volume="1">
    </audio>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addAudio() {
            fileArray = ["file1.mp3", "file2.mp3", "file3.mp3"]
            var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * fileArray.length);
            var x = document.getElementById("music");
            x.innerHTML = "";
            x.innerHTML += '<source src="audio/' + fileArray[num] + '" type="audio/mpeg">';

            x.play(); 
        }

        function secondScreen() {
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = "Second Screen"
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work :( , I feel like this is VERY VERY close to what I need, could it be because it can't find the file location?  Both the HTML and mp3 file are in the same folder, the whole folder is loaded in the application I am running, do I need to specify the directory?  It currently works for me now only stating "myfile.mp3"

Comment: I did a test. The reason is that the browser does not allow the audio file "NotAllowedError: The play method is not allowed by the user ..." to be started automatically. If what you are doing is not for a client but for you. You can figure out how to turn off this setting in the browser

Comment: [How to control audio and video autoplay in Google Chrome](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/02/06/how-to-control-audio-and-video-autoplay-in-google-chrome/) I have not tried the settings from this link but there is a description.

Comment: ok, this HTML file is actually a loading screen for a game, I was only testing in the browser, let me load it in the game and see if it works.  Thanks

Comment: UGHH, it still doesn't work, I know it's not your code, I just can't figure out how to apply it to my application to work.  I have both the HTML and mp3 file in a folder.  I also have a resource file that when the game loads it reads the resource.lua file so it knows to grab the html & mp3 files.  When I load the game it shows the audio box it just wont play anything.

Comment: I edited my original post and added my full code to see if that helps understand my application.

Comment: I edited my post. Please try this to see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I think my application is a little bit differnt though.  This HTML is not being run through a browser.  I am loading a game, and the loading menu for the game uses the HTML code.  In the original code when the loading screen appears the music starts playing automatically.  Any way to incorporate that in so that it will start playing automatically when it's not through a browser?  THANKS AGAIN!!

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for the help!  I got it working, I posted the exact way it worked for me below but I gave you the solution because you lead the way! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is the exact code that ended up working for me, again this HTML file is loaded in a game server as a loading screen so it wont auto play in a browser unless you do the things mentioned by 54ka above.

```
<audio id='music' controls autoplay>

  <source src="" type="audio/mpeg">

</audio>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
       fileArray = ["song1.mp3", "song2.mp3", "song3.mp3"];
       var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * fileArray.length);
       var x = document.getElementById("music");
       x.src = fileArray[num]; 

       var audio = document.getElementById("music");
       audio.volume = 0.2;
       audio.autoplay = true;
       audio.load();
    }

    myFunction()

  </script>
```